# Python embedded. timestamp() return same time over multiple seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, boost-python

I have implemented a system of callbacks. I want to display the time in unix epoch when I call the function.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def my_callback():
    print(datetime.now().timestamp())
    print(datetime.now())
```

In game:

```
First call:
1614270080.0
2021-02-25 19:22:14.304776

Second call after a second:
1614270080.0
2021-02-25 19:22:15.498516

Last call after a 2 seconds:
1614270080.0
2021-02-25 19:22:17.701154
```

Why `datetime.now().timestamp()` return same time? The same problem with `time.time()`

I use Python 3.8 x32

Comment: In how far is the timestamp "not valid"? The unix time ``1614270080.0`` is ``2021-02-25 17:21:20`` in my local timezone of UTC+1 – are you in UTC+3?

Comment: Yes, UTC+3. But with a difference of 3 seconds, timestamp() printed the same results

Comment: So your issue is that the resolution of the timestamp is too low?

Comment: When I do the timestamp in a repl I get 1614275190.042707 ... so where are numbers after the decimal point? Somehow the print(...timestamp()) is not displaying the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, it's strange. The value does not change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a `timestamp` is `float`, which is a floating point type *of the width of the Python build*. A 32-bit float is not sufficient to express the timestamp with second precision:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> def as_f32(num: float): return struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('f', num))[0]
>>> def as_f64(num: float): return struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('d', num))[0]
>>> # 32-bit expressible timestamps in a 10 second range
>>> set(map(as_f32, range(1614270075, 1614270085)))
{1614270080.0}
>>> # 64-bit expressible timestamps in a 10 second range
>>> set(map(as_f64, range(1614270075, 1614270085)))
{1614270075.0, 1614270076.0, 1614270077.0, 1614270078.0, 1614270079.0, 1614270080.0, 1614270081.0, 1614270082.0, 1614270083.0, 1614270084.0}
```

Use a 64-bit build if the full precision is needed.

Comment: Thank you! Spent a lot of time on this.